# Grieving for a loss of not experiencing an event

Tags: behavior

> Sally never got married nor had children but sometimes imagines a 5-year daughter old  talking to her. Sally never at any moment thinks the child is real and in such incidents griefs for being too old and having missed the opportunity for having children.

What do you call this type of regret/grief?

Comment: Whether this is about a person you know (diagnosis can't be provided), or a theoretical case (too little info provided), I can't think of an answer.  If, however, you're interested in learning more about grief itself, from psychological perspective, and how psychologists have attempted to distinguish different kinds of grief, I'm sure that info can be provided.

Comment: I believe you have answered it yourself already. Regret fits the description perfectly

Comment: I want the psychology term grieving a loss that you haven't experienced yourself. The secondary affect of using imagination to cope with it I am not  so interested in

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions are considered off topic without OP showing previous attempts to answer the question